# Difference between "igual a ti" and "igual que tú"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, pronombres, preposiciones

Are both sentences below correct? If so, is there any difference in meaning between them?

- Soy igual a ti.
- Soy igual que tú.

Comment: "Soy igual que tú" seems more common to my ear.  Also "Somos iguales" would be a common way to express this.  And more specifically: "Somos igual de (adj.)" for example "Somos igual de chambeadores" (We're equally hardworking).

Comment: Don't feel bad if you put an accent on *ti*.  That is how it used to be spelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas (DPD)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=x7saBlU6HD6TWcwPVu), both *igual a* and *igual que* are correct when they are followed by a noun or a pronoun. There is no difference between them.

Note that the pronoun *ti* does **not** have an accent.